# Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway with exo player

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am getting this error

```
> Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/io/flutter/x86_debug/1.0.0-890a5fca2e34db413be624fc83aeea8e61d42ce6/x86_debug-1.0.0-890a5fca2e34db413be624fc83aeea8e61d42ce6.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway"
```

my current settings

```
distributionUrl = https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
compileSdkVersion 30
targetSdkVersion 30
```

Comment: Seems like bintray.com is "sunsetted" which seems to mean it has shut down, I have problem building because of this aswell so I'm trying to see why or what package depends on an absolete service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As bintray.com is out of service, most dependencies have moved to mavenCentral. So what worked for me was to add `mavenCentral()` where you have defined `google()` in your android/build.gradle.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() <-- Added
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.32"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral() <-- Added
    }
}
```